# Setting a bitmap to a image view after setting a background resource

Tags: android, bitmap

I set a background resource to a image view then I tried to set a bitmap image to the same image view but then the bitmap image is appearing on top of the background resource. How can i remove this background resource and set a bitmap image

Comment: put your Activity code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `setBipmap(bitmap)` . It actually set like a `android:src="IMAGE"` . So it's overlapping to your background image. So, you have 2 choices.

- set the background image as a image src. exmp : `android:src="@drawable/IMAGE"`. So whe you set the bitmap it won't overlap.
- Or , You can set the bitmap as the background of that imageview . like this `imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BIMAP));`

Comment: @HashanRathanayake,  You welcome, Please accept and put upvote for this answer . :)